# How can I get the route from an object array in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model that is responsible for manipulating resource paths.  I would like to leverage some Rails routing helpers if I can.  I don't want to make any assumptions of the type of resource that is being manipulated, as I would like that to be generic.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects
states that "You can also use url_for with a set of objects, and Rails will automatically determine which route you want:"

```
<%= link_to 'Ad details', url_for([@magazine, @ad]) %>
```

From what I've found url_for helpers typically expect a hash that includes the controller, action, etc.  What I have been looking for is what the above url_for seems to be returning, which is the resource path from an array of objects.  I'm not sure if I'm just using the wrong namespace, but looking through the API docs, I can't find a namespace that would provide the above method.

Just to clarify, I am trying to do something such as below in a model:

```
resource_array = [parent_resource, child_resource]
resource_path = url_for(resource_array)
```

I usually keep any routing code out of a model class, but this class is dedicated to manipulating resource paths.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
This is the syntax that I ended up using:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_path(resource)
```

**Edit (2):**
I feel like there has to be a nicer way to do this, but this is what I have right now.

```
resource_path = ''
resource_array.each do |resource|
  resource_path += '/' + resource.class.name.pluralize.underscore + '/' + resource.id.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking for, but `url_for` is an instance method of the module `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`, so you need to `extend` or `include` that module to gain access to the method.

Comment: I ended up using polymorphic_path.  I had sworn that I had tried the above (in question edit). syntax the other day, but this seems to work as I'd like.  I found the documentation on account of your suggestion, so thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: Actually I had forgotten that I was wanting to get this to work with nested resources.  I might just build the resource path by hand.